# How to go from list comprehension to loop in this case?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have to perform the following action without using list comprehensions.
I have a list that looks like the following one:

```
["Mi Fa Sol", 'Mi', "Mi Fa Sol La Si", "Do Si", " Mi Si Fa", "Fa"]
```

What I want to obtain is a list like the following one:

```
["Mi", "Fa", "Sol", "Mi", "Mi", "Fa", "Sol", "La", "Si", "Do", "Si", "Mi", "Si", "Fa", "Fa"]
```

I can do that in the following way, I think:

```
    lst = [elem.strip().split() for elem in lst]
    lst = [elem for sub_lst in lst for elem in sub_lst]
```

But I have no idea how to accomplish the same result without list comprehensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current version using two separate list comprehensions can be simplified to use a single list comprehension instead:

```
lst = [e for elem in lst for e in elem.split()]
```

But, if you want to use a traditional `for` loop instead, then you can loop through each `elem` of `lst` as you currently do, and use [`list.extend()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) to add the splitted elements to a result list `res`:

```
lst = ["Mi Fa Sol", 'Mi', "Mi Fa Sol La Si", "Do Si", " Mi Si Fa", "Fa"]
res = []
for elem in lst:
    res.extend(elem.split())
print(res)
```

Output:

```
['Mi', 'Fa', 'Sol', 'Mi', 'Mi', 'Fa', 'Sol', 'La', 'Si', 'Do', 'Si', 'Mi', 'Si', 'Fa', 'Fa']
```

You can assign `res` back to `lst` if needed afterwards.

Side note: since you use the default delimiter for `split()`, you can also omit the redundant `strip()` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a functional approach:

```py
>>> music = ["Mi Fa Sol", 'Mi', "Mi Fa Sol La Si", "Do Si", " Mi Si Fa", "Fa"]
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, map(str.split, music))
['Mi', 'Fa', 'Sol', 'Mi', 'Mi', 'Fa', 'Sol', 'La', 'Si', 'Do', 'Si', 'Mi', 'Si', 'Fa', 'Fa']
```

The lambda expression could be replaced by `operator.add`:

```py
>>> import operator
>>> reduce(operator.add, map(str.split, music))
['Mi', 'Fa', 'Sol', 'Mi', 'Mi', 'Fa', 'Sol', 'La', 'Si', 'Do', 'Si', 'Mi', 'Si', 'Fa', 'Fa']
```

For the snippets above to work in work in Python 3 you have to include this sentence:

```py
from functools import reduce
```